# set background picture for qframe

Tags: qt

Actually I have 2 questions... I'm trying to set background picture for the window and give it full window size even when i maximize it and i have a qframe in which I'm trying to set another picture as background for it. what's i'm facing is that the window's background pic doesn't take the size of the window when maximized and the picture for the qframe doesn't appear at all here's my code and a picture of the result

```
QPixmap bkgnd("./Qt_logo_2016.svg.png");
bkgnd = bkgnd.scaled(this->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);
QPalette palette;
palette.setBrush(QPalette::Background, bkgnd);
this->setPalette(palette);

QPixmap bkgnd1("./Background.png");
bkgnd1 = bkgnd1.scaled(this->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);
palette.setBrush(QPalette::Background, bkgnd1);
ui->widget->setPalette(palette);
```

[image]

Comment: provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this  : 
for the window (or widget) it's better to override the paint event function, this way you will not need to rescale the picture.

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.drawImage(this->rect(),QImage("windowImage.png"));

    QMainWindow::paintEvent(e);

}
```

same thing for the Frame, make a class that inherits from QFrame and override the paint event function

Header file:

```
#pragma once

#include <QFrame>
#include <QPainter>

class CFrame : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit CFrame(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) override;


};
```

cpp:

```
#include "cframe.h"

CFrame::CFrame(QWidget *parent) : QFrame(parent)
{

}

void CFrame::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    QPainter painter(this);

    painter.drawImage(this->rect(),QImage("frameImage.png"));

    QFrame::paintEvent(e);

}
```

promote the QFrame that you are using to CFrame ;)